# Woocommerce Custom Product Types for user role based visibility

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a bit of a quandary and I'm hoping someone might be able to talk me through the potential limitations and drawbacks for my solution:

**Issue:**

I have retailers, technicians, sponsored individuals, and regular customers that will be accessing my website, and each one has their own pricing on my products. Additionally, the technicians and retailers have access to purchase individual parts as well as bulk orders, and customers get access to additional products on purchase of specific products.

**Multi-Price Solution:**

Add a filter method to a helper class and have it filter the prices for the general products taxonomy.

**Product Visibility:**

Create three separate product types that will hold the "private" products and set user role permissions accordingly.

**Final issue:**

How can I dynamically generate custom product types from an associative array that contains a product type name and ID? It seems to be impossible from what I've seen since the custom product class needs to be a static name, and a variable can't be used to declare a class name. IE this wouldn't work:

```
 namespace Plugin\Includes\API;
 
 defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
 
 require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__,3)).'\woocommerce\includes\abstracts\abstract-wc-product.php');
 
 use Plugin\Includes\Base\Controller;
 
 class CustomProductAPI extends Controller{
 
     public function register(){
         foreach($this->productList as $key => $value ){
             $classname = 'WC_Product_'.$value;
             $this->create_custom_products($classname,$key)
         }
     }
 
     public function create_custom_products($className, $productID){
         class $className extends WC_Product {
             public function __construct( $product ) {
                 $this->product_type = $productID;
                 parent::__construct( $product );
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Price Solution: https://woocommerce.com/products/role-based-pricing-for-woocommerce/

Product Visibility: do normal products and add custom meta field to set your visability parameter, then hook on action "pre_get_posts" and depending what user does query and what permissions hi has, add extra meta query to filter out what you need. You can do custom whing by user role or custom meta added on user

you not geting code, just an idea, sorry.

Comment: Role based pricing for woocommerce literally just adds a filter to the product price based on the user viewing it, and they want $79 a year to use it and it will just add to the already bloated woocommerce platform. I'm not going to pay to have a half second added to my page load times when a simple filter will handle that. As for adding metaboxes, I'm trying to avoid as many meta queries as possible to keep my website snappy. I already have a TON of things going on in the background. I've basically coded an entire ERP system into WordPress from scratch, I'm just not familiar with woocommerce.